# teacher in German: Lehrer, Master, Pädagog, Lehrmeister, Professor

Tags: vocabulary

I have translated teacher into German. There is: Lehrer, Master, Pädagog, Lehrmeister, Professor.

I am studying the diffeence between them.

- *Which one of them is a kindergarden teacher?*
- *Which one of them is a high school teacher?*
- *Which one of them is a university teacher?*
- *How about art school teacher?*
- *How about instructor in car driving/climbing?*
- *Is one of them a hypernym?*

Hypothesis: Lehrer is a hypernym, Professor is a university one

Note: I prefer Hochdeutsch.

Comment: So many questions, so few research facts mentioned. What about getting a decent dictionary instead of single word translation you use?

Comment: Is there only one word in English? Do you really say university teacher?

Answer (score 4):

> hypothesis: Lehrer is a hypernym, Professor is a university one

The stand-alone word "*Lehrer*" is typically a teacher at a school, not at a university.

However in combination with other words the word "*Lehrer*" is a hypernym (Example: "*Hochschullehrer*")

"*Professor*" is a teacher at an university or a similar institution.

> Pädagog**e**

... (note the "e" at the end of the word) is any person whose profession has to do with the education of people - typically children.

A "*Lehrer*" at an elementary school would definitely be a "*Pädagoge*".

If a university "*Professor*" is a "*Pädagoge*" is a good question: **I** understand the word in a way that the task of a "*Pädagoge*" is also forming the personality of people. A university professor "only" teaches knowledge.

> Master

Forget it.

> M**ei**ster

**Today** this is the title of a person who has a special (6-year?) education in his job (e.g. "*Bäckermeister*" is a baker having such an education).

For example each bakery (even if it has only three employees) must have one person having this education. Only persons having such an education are allowed to train persons who are new in the job.

> Lehrmeister

This word is sometimes used for a person who had great influence on a person who learned from this person. It is not used very often.

> Which one of them is a kindergarden teacher?

These persons are officially called "*Erzieher*". Many people call these People "*Kindergärtnerin*" (as far as they are female) - what women doing this job do **not** like at all.

In Germany the "*Kindergärten*" are institutions for children up to 6 years which are not obligatory. Their mission is only forming the personality of the children and not teaching them anything.

Therefore these persons are "*Pädagogen*" but not teachers (and therefore not "*Lehrer*").

> Which one of them is a high school teacher?

Any teacher who is not teaching at the university is a "*Lehrer*". Maybe in combination with another word:

> Grundschullehrer

teacher at an elementary school

> Berufsschullehrer

teacher at a professional school

> How about art school teacher?

They could be called "*Leherer*" or something like "*Kunstlehrer*" or "*Musiklehrer*" (musical teacher).

> How about instructor in car driving/climbing?

The word "*Lehrer*" is used in combination here:

*Fahrlehrer* = driving instructor

*Tauchlehrer* = diving instructor

You typically don't use the stand-alone word "*Lehrer*" in this case.

Comment: Please change the part about Kindergarten-Erzieher being mostly women. While it is true that mostly women do this job, it is not *better* to say *Erzieherin*.

Comment: Maybe add a remark that *Kunstlehrer* is not an umbrella term for teachers teaching any form of art, but specifically painting and sculpting. From the current wording, it doesn't become clear that *Kunstlehrer* and *Musiklehrer* are disjoint groups (or at least disjoint occupations - as it *is* possible that a given teacher teaches two subjects, *Kunst* (painting and sculpting) and *Musik*). At least, that's my impression from schools that are not specifically art schools. I'd expect expertise at art schools to be rather more specific.

Comment: In Austria *Professor* covers a lot of non-university teachers too, as well as a lot of people who aren't teachers at all.